# Chaincode can't find index

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to query the data from CouchDB and have made an index to be able to sort the data.
But no matter what I try, I always get the following error:

> Error: GET_QUERY_RESULT failed, No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields

I have put the index in the `META_INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes` dir and according the logs is the index successfully created.

This is my query string:

```
var queryString = {};
queryString.selector = {};
queryString.selector.docType = docType;
queryString.selector.assetId = {"$gt" : null};
queryString.sort= [{assetId : "desc"}];
queryString.limit = 1;
queryString.use_index = ["_design/indexAssetIdDoc" ,  "indexAssetId"];
```

and this is the index:

```
{
    "index":
    {
        "fields":["docType","assetId"]
    },
    "ddoc":"indexAssetIdDoc", 
    "name":"indexAssetId",
    "type":"json"
}
```

when using the query and index in the couchdb webapplication is works perfectly.

pictures:
[index creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGdzN.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAE9g.png)

Comment: Do not paste images of text. They are hard to read (especially when they're links, and not inline), and are impossible to read for the visually impaired. They also can't be indexed or searched. Instead, copy and paste the text directly into the post.

Comment: mango doesn't have a very advanced query system and generally wont find equivalent indexes given the query, so I think you need to create a separate index matching your sort field alone (or in this case you could just add docType as the first sort field). If you need it to be as efficient as using the index you made you may in some cases need a partial index to drop other docTypes ahead of time.. (comment ammended)